# How to translate text using curl php

Tags: php-curl

please i need help. I want to translate some text from a database using curl php.
. i have javascript file that is performing an ajax call to that database after every five seconds. And the db it self contains 150 rows but the the curl does not run 150 times because i have included a restriction.

```
    $translation = $row['Message'];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => -1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'q='.$translation.'&target=es&source=en',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Accept-Encoding: application/gzip",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: //API KEY HERE//  ",
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ],
]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
       $data = json_decode($response, true);
       $translated = $data['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
       echo $translate;
}
```

output:
{"message":"Too many requests"}